# Amount of employees whose average salary by department < 50000

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm confused with task that sounds like this:

```
Display the number of employees whose average half-year salary for the department in which they work does not exceed 50,000
```

I'm not sure abount syntax that i need to use and command sequence

`SELECT COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID) AS 'Total' FROM HR.EMPLOYEES GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID WHERE AVG(SALARY*6) <= 50000`

I tried this but i dont know how to write the query properly

Here is a photo of DB(i cant provide code snippet)[image]

Comment: Is that really how the question is worded? An employee has a salary, not an average salary. So employee 100 has a salary of 24,000. What is that employee's average salary? Very poorly worded question IMHO.

Comment: Every department has an average monthly salary(for example id=90 has (24000+17000+17000)/3) average montly salary. To get an average for half-year we need to multiply it by 6. Then we need to figure out amount of employees whose department half-year average salary is less or equal to 50000

Comment: `number of employees whose average half-year salary`... the word `whose` is referring to the employee in this sentence. Tell your professor to reword the question.

Comment: i refolmulated so help me now pls

Answer (score 0):

you can use analytical function to calculate the average salary.

-- untested

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT employee_id,   department_id, 
    round(avg(salary) over (partition by department_id), 2) avg_sal
  from HR.EMPLOYEES
) WHERE avg_sal > 50000;
```